# Implement NotifyPropertyChangedListener for Doctrine2 in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've read the docs on [Notify Change Tracking Policy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify) but I couldn't find anything on how to register a listener via services.

Can this be done in Symfony2?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Those docs are for lifecycle listeners. Looking into this further I don't think you can actually register notify change tracking listeners. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct from the mouth of [@beberlei](https://twitter.com/beberlei/status/403090052122947584) it's not possible to register PropertyChangedListeners via a DI tag.

Here's how I plan to approach this:

1. Use PostLoad event to set the listener for existing entities
2. Use a manager / factory method to create new entities and inject the listener

Potentially I could fire a custom event in both cases in order to listen for other subscribers.